# Fluent Nhibernate : Self referential many to many

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

With this class and mapping:

```
Public class Something
{
    public int Id;
    public IList<Something> Similarthings { get; set; }
}

public class SomtehingMapping
    {
        public SomtehingMapping()
        {
            Map(x => x.Id);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Similarthings )
               .Table("SomethingsToSimilarthings")
               .ParentKeyColumn("SomethingA_Id")
               .ChildKeyColumn("SomethingB_Id")
               .Cascade.All();
         }
}
```

You end up with this:

```
Table SomethingsToSimilarthings
-------------------------------
SomethingA_Id    SomethingB_Id
111              222
222              111
```

**Is there any way of defining this mapping so that the bidirectional relationship is expressed using just one database row?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up the **inverse** mapping attribute to **true** like that?

```
public class SomtehingMapping
    {
        public SomtehingMapping()
        {
            Map(x => x.Id);
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Similarthings )
               .Inverse()
               .Table("SomethingsToSimilarthings")
               .ParentKeyColumn("SomethingA_Id")
               .ChildKeyColumn("SomethingB_Id")
               .Cascade.All();
         }
}
```

An alternative would be to explicitly define the other side of the association and mark that as `inverse="true"`

Comment: Haven't tried it. Difficult to imagine what Inverse=true would mean in this context.  I'll try it and get back.